# Eclipse image views moving them

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to android development and am trying to move 2 of my image views so it shows 2 buttons parallel under one another. Here's a screenshot of what it looks like so far:[CLICK HERE TO VIEW MY PROBLEM](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63060352/a34fc1af568669ddec491dc1d1e85c86.png)

Updated code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TopTwoButtons"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background_meduim"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ListButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:src="@drawable/list_button_medium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ListButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/search_button_medium" />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/BottomTwoButtons"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/TopTwoButtons"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/InfoButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/info_button_medium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/PopularButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/popular_button_medium" >



</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my code now. I'm getting an error on line 29 on the second Relative Layout which holds the two second buttons. Thanks and sorry for being an idiot, I'm just getting used to doing things on this site.

Comment: Ok. How u want to display images??

Comment: I would like to place the buttons so there is 2 on the top line, and 2 underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As u said, i am adding the layout file. Please check the below code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/TopTwoButtons"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background_meduim"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ListButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:src="@drawable/list_button_medium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ListButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/search_button_medium" />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/BottomTwoButtons"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/TopTwoButtons"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/InfoButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/info_button_medium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/PopularButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/popular_button_medium" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm using a Linear Layout, I'm guessing that would be the same concept?

Comment: Yes same concept. If you are using LinearLayout, place `android:orientation="vertical"` for each of the linearLayouts. Better to use RelativeLayouts which i have placed above.

Comment: @Jack Do u find the solution?

Comment: When I added the XML code you had in the Relative layout that I didn't have in my code for the Linear Layout, things got messed up and got an error(Exception raised during rendering: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup), not sure how to resolve this and don't know what's wrong in my code.

Comment: Also, How can I show you my code, you aren't allowed to have that many characters in these comment boxes, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer... Can u please UPVOTE my answer... If u want show ur code, Just edit your question by clicking `edit` under question...

Comment: Also, I cannot up UPVOTE your answer because I need at-least 15 reputation score and I only have 1 because of my unclear question I asked.

Comment: @Jack i have edited my answer wit the latest code. Please check and update. No errors now. This should work...

Comment: Thank you, that error I was previously getting is now gone but my other two buttons(Info and popular)still aren't showing at all. Any help?